# Laravel UniSharp file manager is uploaded but images are not displayed

Tags: php, laravel, unisharp-file-manager

I am using UniSharp file manager package in Laravel.

I have no problem uploading,
But images are not displayed.

After executing the `php artisan storage:link` command, only the `storage` folder is displayed and there are no uploaded files in it.

.env
`APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`

Laravel Framework 8.6.0

unisharp: master

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

I removed the storage folder from the public folder and ran the `php artisan storage:link` command again. The problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution
Within `GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php` change:

```
\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($sink);
```

to

```
\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor();
```